# Cancel a jQuery AJAX call before it returns?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery dialog box that opens and then an AJAX call is made.  I would like to make it so that if the dialog box is closed or the cancel button is pressed the AJAX call is canceled and its callback function is not called.  I can think of some ways to do it with a variable like so:

```
  function doStuff(){
    var doCallback = true;
    $('#dialog').dialog({
      title: 'Dialog Title',
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
          doCallback = false;
          doSomethingElse();
        }
      }
    });
    $.get('url/url/url', function(data){
      if(doCallback){
        doTheSuccessThing(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

But, somehow that feels dirty to me and it doesn't actually stop the AJAX call from completing.  Is there a built-in way to cancel an AJAX call in progress?

Comment: Not something I've tried, but the get() method returns the underlying XMLHttpRequest, which can be abort()ed. Would that help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancelling previous ajax request jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342438/cancelling-previous-ajax-request-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so based off of the suggestion to use the XmlHttpRequest object returned by the $.get function I came up with this:

```
function doStuff(){
    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                        url : 'url/url/url',
                        type : "GET",
                        success : function(data){
                          ajaxRequest = null;
                          doSuccessStuff(data);
                        }
                      });

    $('#dialog').dialog({
      title: 'Stuff Dialog',
      bgiframe: true,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
          if (ajaxRequest)
            ajaxRequest.abort();
          doCancelStuff();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

It seems to work and feels cleaner to me.

Comment: don't forget to check for ajaxRequest being null. you should reset it also in the 'success' method - then you can judge if there is an active ajax request or not

Comment: `doSuccessStuff()` may still be invoked even after you abort the request. See my answer below for a technique to guard against this.

Answer (score 18):

When I have a callback that may be fired multiple times, but I want to only use the last one, I use this pattern:

```
var resultsXHR, resultsTimer, resultsId=0;
$('input').keyup(function(){
  clearTimeout(resultsTimer);                     // Remove any queued request
  if (resultsXHR) resultsXHR.abort();             // Cancel request in progress
  resultsTimer = setTimeout(function(){           // Record the queued request
    var id = ++resultsId;                         // Record the calling order
    resultsXHR = $.get('/results',function(data){ // Capture request in progress
      resultsXHR = null;                          // This request is done
      if (id!=resultsId) return;                  // A later request is pending
      // ... actually do stuff here ...
    });  
  },500);                                         // Wait 500ms after keyup
});
```

The `abort()` alone is not sufficient to prevent the success callback from being invoked; you may still find your callback run even though you tried to cancel the request. This is why it's necessary to use the `resultsId` tracker and have your callback stop processing if another, later, overlapping callback is ready to go.

Given how common and cumbersome this is, I think it's a good idea to wrap it up in a re-usable fashion that doesn't require you to come up with a unique triplet of local variable names for each you want to handle:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.bindDelayedGet = function(event,delay,url,dataCallback,dataType,callback){
    var xhr, timer, ct=0;
    return this.bind(event,function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if (xhr) xhr.abort();
      timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var id = ++ct;
        xhr = $.get(url,dataCallback && dataCallback(),function(data){
          xhr = null;
          if (id==ct) callback(data);
        },dataType);
      },delay);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

// In action
var inp = $('#myinput').bindDelayedGet('keyup',400,'/search',
  function(){ return {term:inp.val()}; },
  'html',
  function(html){ $('#searchResults').clear().append(html); }
);
```

*You can find the above code discussed in more detail [on my website](http://phrogz.net/jquery-bind-delayed-get).*

Comment: Is success always called on a cancelled request? If so, what's the point of cancelling? If not, when does that happen?

Comment: @xr280xr failure is usually returned on an request abort so it's unlikely to hit the success function but possible. The point of cancelling is so the UI isn't waiting for the ajax call to return (and can appropriately display that state to the end user). It happens almost immediately since it's a client side cancel.

Answer (score 5):

No method in jQuery, but you can just use XmlHttpRequest object returned from the jQuery get/post/ajax functions.

From the [jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2006/12/12/jquery-104/):

```
// Perform a simple Ajax request
var req = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/user/list/",
  success: function(data) {
    // Do something with the data...
    // Then remove the request.
    req = null;
  }
});

// Wait for 5 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  // If the request is still running, abort it.
  if ( req ) req.abort();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears so, though I've never done it.

`$.get` returns an `XmlHttpRequest` object, which has an `abort()` method you can call.  Maybe try that?

Answer (score 0):

If you put a conditional in the script you ajax to where on the condition being true you output your html, else, you don't output anything, then you can do simple     if(html) check in the success function like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "url.php",
      data: "data="+data,
      success: function(html)
          { 
              if(html){
              $("#container").empty().html(html);
              }
      }
});
```

in this example, url.php could look something like this:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];

if($data=="whatever"){
     echo "<div>Hello</div>";
}else{}
```

This worked for me. I know this post is old, but hope it helps someone.