# Cancelling previous ajax request jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

From what I've read the general solution to this is as follows:

```
var DataRequest = $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
```

and then `DataRequest.abort()` in the `beforeSend` ajax event. However, this results in NO requests being sent.

What I'm trying to achieve is to abort any ajax operations that are declared as DataRequest (for example), and allow only the latest request to proceed. Currently I have a button that when clicked starts a request and adds a loading spinner. If I click it many times, I just get a bunch of loading spinners filling up my page. How can I prevent this?

Here's the relevant code:

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $('<div class="grid"></div>')
        .attr('id', 'loading')
        .hide()
        .insertBefore('#output')
        .fadeIn();
},

success: function(data) {
    $('#loading').hide(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the pattern I use when I need to have multiple requests and only process the last:

```
var fooXHR, fooCounter=0;
$(...).bind( 'someEvent', function(){
  // Do the Right Thing to indicate that we don't care about the request anymore
  if (fooXHR) fooXHR.abort();

  var token = ++fooCounter;
  fooXHR = $.get( ..., function(data){
    // Even aborted XHR may cause the callback to be invoked
    if (token != fooCounter) return;

    // At this point we know that we're using the data from the latest request
  });
});
```

**Edit**: I have wrapped this functionality up in a plugin-like method call here:
[Cancel a jQuery AJAX call before it returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434519/can-you-cancel-a-jquery-ajax-call-before-it-returns/5746018#5746018)

Comment: The token is best set _before_ aborting the xhr, I think :)

Comment: @WouterC You write that as though it should be obvious why doing it that way is desirable, but it is not obvious to me. Please elaborate: why do you think the order of actions should be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the loading spinner as part of the markup and hidden (or inserted on page load). Then have the code in beforeSend to show it, that way you won't have multiple spinner inserted when button is pressed multiple times.

```
beforeSend: function () {
   $('#loading").show();
});
```

Unless you intentionally want the button to be pressed multiple times...consider disabling the button after the first click. Much simpler than trying to abort the last ajax request.

Comment: Disabling the button is the simple solution but I'd like to not impose that limitation. Also, the problem that Phrogz touches upon is that sometimes your ajax callback gets hit even if you make a new request.