# MVC c# multiple ajax requests handling, how to manage?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have an autocomplete field searching on each hit and I made it send requests each 500ms.

But sometimes the search controller is answering after around 5 seconds. The problem is that each request is still in the stack, and all requests will be completed even if the client is not searching anymore.

That makes the client wait for further actions based on ajax, until all previous requests will be completed.
The solution I'm trying to implement is the usage of .abort() method in ajax that way:

```
var currentRequest =null;
function keyUp(...){
if(currentRequest!=null){
  currrentRequest.abort();
}
currentRequest = $.get(...);
```

But in spite of this, on the server side, the controller still received all pending requests, that were cancelled with `.abort()`.

Is there any way to detect a client connect state to avoid processing requests server side?

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript libraries for the autocomplete etc?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342438/cancelling-previous-ajax-request-jquery

Comment: I'm using own autocomplete @Tr1stan, and this is a different question, because, I'm using the .abort() method, and it is working, but, I also have to cancel the request at server side, detecting that it was aborted from client, this is my question.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side code, you could use the `Response.IsClientConnected` property to determine whether or not the request has been aborted on the client side or not. Therefore you could free up the resources currently being used on requests that are no longer required.

I've not actually used this myself, but in principle I think you could achieve what you're after.

On a side note, you really want to optimise the code in your controller that is taking around 5 seconds to return a value, having this amount of delay on a dynamic UI item such as an Autocomplete isn't going to give a good user experience.