# How can I limit the scope of a Javascript counter variable by object?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I'm using @[Phrogz's quick script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342438/cancelling-previous-ajax-request-jquery) to cancel all but the last AJAX request using the following:

```
var fooXHR, fooCounter=0;
$('div').bind( 'click', function(){
  // Do the Right Thing to indicate that we don't care about the request anymore
  if (fooXHR) fooXHR.abort();

  var token = ++fooCounter;
  fooXHR = $.get( ..., function(data){
    // Even aborted XHR may cause the callback to be invoked
    if (token != fooCounter) return;

    // At this point we know that we're using the data from the latest request
  });
});
```

This script works very well, but if I load 3 `div`s at once on pageload and expect to load results for all 3, the above script will only show the last one (because the first two are aborted based on the script above).

Can you point me in the right direction to limit the above script by the enclosed DOM element?

For example...

```
<div id="one">1. run ajax on pageload and on click</div>
<div id="two">2. run ajax on pageload and on click</div>
<div id="three">3. run ajax on pageload and on click</div>
```

I want all three divs to return the ajax request on pageload or click.  And I want to retain the functionality of canceling the previous AJAX request on click.  BUT, I don't want a click on `div#one` to cancel an ajax request called from `div#two`.

You follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a hash to store your xhr and counter variable for each `div`:

```
var requests = {};
$('div').bind( 'click', function(){
  var div = this;

  // init the entry for the div
  if (requests[div] === undefined) {
    requests[div] = {};
    requests[div].counter = 0;
  }

  // abort the old request
  if (requests[div].xhr !== undefined) {
    requests[div].xhr.abort();
  } 

  var token = ++requests[div].counter;
  request[div].xhr = $.get( ..., function(data) {
    // check for correct request
    if (token !== requests[div].counter) return;

    // ...
  });
});
```