# how to abort a $.post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this event on keydown:

```
$.post("search.php", { s: $('#box_s').val()},
               function(data) {
                  /**/
               }
});
```

the problem is that as many keydown as many requests and sometimes older requests override recent requests results

so i would need to

```
$('input#box_s').keydown(function(){
     abort_previous_post();
     $.post("search.php", { s: $('#box_s').val()},
                   function(data) {
                      /**/
                   }
    });
});
```

is that posible?

Comment: similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434519/can-you-cancel-a-jquery-ajax-call-before-it-returns and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery

Answer (score 3):

You can throttle it so that a request is not made until the user has stopped typing for x milliseconds. 250-400ms seems a good value:

```
function throttle( fn, time ) {
    var timer = 0;

    return function() {
        window.clearTimeout( timer );
        var self = this,
            args = [].slice.call( arguments );


        timer = setTimeout( function() {
            return fn.apply( self, args );
        }, time );
    };

}
```

And usage:

```
$('input#box_s').keydown( throttle( function(){

     $.post("search.php", { s: $('#box_s').val()},
                   function(data) {
                      /**/
                   }
    });
}, 400 ) );
```

In this case a request is made after the user starts typing and then stops for 400ms.

Comment: what if the client doesn't receive response in 400 ms?  it will override the most recent.

Comment: @meze it depends on use case, auto-suggest is pretty useless for example if it takes more than 400ms. Google has autosuggest on 100ms and instant on 1000ms.

Comment: Nice generic throttling implementation! You could potentially have another one specific for fetches (e.g. throttleFetch) that could also handle the cancellation or invalidation of the previous fetch.

Comment: @Esailija How do you know 1000ms on instant? I type a 4 letters word and it does 4 queries in a row.

Comment: @meze I see `setTimeout` called with 1000 as argument for time and approx 1 second later the result appears. You could dig in with breakpoints but it's a mess with obfuscated code.

Comment: @Esailija if you "hook" in `XMLHttpRequest.send`, you'll see requests are sent immediately. The result appears after 1 second because of latency.

Comment: @meze you are probably right, I thought those were for the suggestions but there doesn't appear any separate request for instants. They are also sending a lot of markup as well instead of just data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it something like this:

```
var requestCount = 0;

$('input#box_s').keydown(function(){
     requestCount++;
     var thisRequestCount = requestCount;
     $.post("search.php", { ingredientes_s: $('#box_s').val()},
                   function(data) {
                      if(thisRequestCount!=requestCount) return;
                      /**/
                   }
    });
});
```

Comment: This makes a whole bunch of unnecessary requests to the server. The more users you have or the larger datasets you have, this really becomes an unacceptable solution.

Comment: @alecgorge google live search doesn't have any timeouts and they have many users. They are fine ;)

Comment: Submitting a request doesn't imply high bandwidth.  It might cost an extra 400 bytes per second if you don't throttle a simple query.  More complex ones, there very well could be a problem.. but the question implies just what was typed is being sent.

Comment: Google has spent considerable time, money and effort to make search results come in as quickly as possible. For most developers, we are talking about a FULLTEXT or LIKE query against a MySQL database. Minimizing hits on the server, on PHP and on MySQL is a wise idea--especially when the end result is very similar.

Comment: @alecgorge I didn't say it's better, it was to "this really becomes an unacceptable solution."

Comment: Good point: processing the request might cost a lot more server-side than is apparent from looking at the client.  I'm still leaving my answer as is, because it answers the question as it was asked.

Comment: But it does become high bandwidth because the requests aren't canceled. They are still processed, just nothing is done with the data. If I type in something like "this is a really long search term", the browser will make a request, the server will have to process and the browser will download results for "t", "th", "thi", "this", etc. That is high bandwidth and high load on the server.

Comment: you really are making a lot of assumptions about what the server is doing, but I don't think that's justified.  If i was trying to make something similar to live search, I'd limit the results to maybe 10 items.  The response would be maybe a kilobyte.  With multi-megabyte pages these days, that's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not start the request unless there has been a slight delay:

```
var timeoutID;
$('#box_s').keydown(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
        $.post("search.php", { ingredientes_s: $('#box_s').val()}, function(data) {
            /** **/
        });
     }, 500);
});
```

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sR74V/) for a demo.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, which was, how do you abort the request?

Comment: Correct, but this is a better solution for what he is trying to do. Aborting the request is a common way of thinking about it, but it is incredibly inefficient and should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

The post call is just a convince method for the Ajax handler, so capture the xhr, and abort it.

```
var jqxhr;

$('input#box_s').keydown(function(){
     if (jqxhr) jqxhr.abort();
     $.post("search.php", { ingredientes_s: $('#box_s').val()},
                   function(data) {
                      /**/
                   }
    });
});
```