# Stop PHP with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a JavaScript functions which calls a PHP function through AJAX.
The PHP function has a `set_time_limit(0)` for its purposes.
Is there any way to stop that function when I want, for example with an HTML button event?

---

I want to explain better the situation:
I have a php file which uses a stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest) php function to retrieve a stream in my local network. The function has to work until I want: I can stop it at the end of the stream or when I want. So I can use a button to start and a button to stop. The problem is the new instance created by the ajax call, in fact I can't work on it because it is not the function that is recording but it is another instance. I tried MireSVK's suggest but it doesn't worked!

Comment: Why do you want this functionality? There may be a better way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: so like you wanna make a daemon?

Comment: What exactly is your function doing that it needs an infinite time limit? Is it always "listening", is it querying a database, etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you cancel a jQuery AJAX call before it returns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434519/can-you-cancel-a-jquery-ajax-call-before-it-returns)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the function. If it is a while loop checking for certain condition every time, then you could add a condition that is modifiable from outside the script (e.g. make it check for a file, and create / delete that file as required)

It looks like a bad idea, however. Why you want to do it?

Comment: let's say it is on a loop which have to stop when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var running = true;

function doSomething(){

       //do something........
}

setInterval(function(){if(running){doSomething()}},2000); ///this runs do something every 2 seconds
```

on button click simply set `running = false`;

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like:

```
set_time_limit(0);

while(true==true){//infinite loop

 doSomething(); //your code

}
```

Let's upgrade it

```
set_time_limit(0);

session_start();
$_SESSION['do_a_loop'] = true;

function should_i_stop_loop(){

   @session_start(); 

   if( $_SESSION['do_a_loop'] == false ) {

    //let's stop a loop
    exit();

   }

   session_write_close(); 

}

while(true==true){

 doSomething();

 should_i_stop_loop(); //your new function

}
```

Create new file stopit.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['do_a_loop'] = false;
```

All you have to do now is create a request on stopit.php file (with ajax or something)

Edit code according to your needs, this is point. One of many solutions.

*Sorry for my English*

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this isn't possible (sort of).

Each time you make an AJAX call to a PHP script the script spawns a new instance of itself. Thus anything you send to it will be sent to a new operation, not the operation you had previously started.

There are a number of workarounds.

- Use readystate 3 in AJAX to create a non closing connection to the PHP script, however that isn't supported cross browser and probably won't work in IE (not sure about IE 10).
- Look into socket programming in PHP, which allows you to create a script with one instance that you can connect to multiple times.
- Have PHP check a third party. I.E have one script running in a loop checking a file or a database, then connect to another script to modify that file or database. The original script can be remotely controlled by what you write to the file/database.
- Try another programming language (this is a silly option, but I'm a fan of node). Node.js does this sort of thing very very easily.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can found examples of your 1 e 2 ideas?